# Error when creating an object TriangulatedMesh

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, javafx-8, javafx-3d

[image]
I want to create a figure in the form of the letter T
When I create an object with these points, the exception drops
Has anyone come across this?

I use FXyz3D

```
final List<Point3D> points = new ArrayList<>(//I am trying to create an array of points (x, y, 0)
Arrays.asList(
new Point3D(0,150,0),
new Point3D(0, 90,0),
new Point3D(10,90,0),
new Point3D(30,90,0),
new Point3D(40,90,0),
new Point3D(10,0,0),
new Point3D(30,0,0),
new Point3D(40,150,0))
            );
TriangulatedMesh customShape = new 
TriangulatedMesh(points,20);//Exception falls on this place
```

This is the console output when I run the program

I can’t understand what the problem is.

```html
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Intersecting Constraints
 at org.poly2tri.triangulation.delaunay.sweep.DTSweep.flipEdgeEvent(DTSweep.java:657)
 at org.poly2tri.triangulation.delaunay.sweep.DTSweep.edgeEvent(DTSweep.java:631)
 at org.poly2tri.triangulation.delaunay.sweep.DTSweep.edgeEvent(DTSweep.java:626)
 at org.poly2tri.triangulation.delaunay.sweep.DTSweep.edgeEvent(DTSweep.java:348)
 at org.poly2tri.triangulation.delaunay.sweep.DTSweep.sweep(DTSweep.java:110)
 at org.poly2tri.triangulation.delaunay.sweep.DTSweep.triangulate(DTSweep.java:72)
 at org.poly2tri.Poly2Tri.triangulate(Poly2Tri.java:108)
 at org.poly2tri.Poly2Tri.triangulate(Poly2Tri.java:60)
 at org.fxyz3d.shapes.primitives.TriangulatedMesh.createMesh(TriangulatedMesh.java:285)
 at org.fxyz3d.shapes.primitives.TriangulatedMesh.createMesh(TriangulatedMesh.java:218)
 at org.fxyz3d.shapes.primitives.TriangulatedMesh.updateMesh(TriangulatedMesh.java:112)
 at org.fxyz3d.shapes.primitives.TriangulatedMesh.<init>(TriangulatedMesh.java:103)
 at org.fxyz3d.shapes.primitives.TriangulatedMesh.<init>(TriangulatedMesh.java:93)
 at org.fxyz3d.shapes.primitives.TriangulatedMesh.<init>(TriangulatedMesh.java:90)
 at org.fxyz3d.shapes.primitives.TriangulatedMesh.<init>(TriangulatedMesh.java:82)
 at sampleFxyz3D.Sample.start(Sample.java:89)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
 at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
 ... 1 more
Exception running application sampleFxyz3D.Sample
```

Comment: Make sure your points are ordered forming a closed polygon.

Comment: You were right, I solved this problem.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final List<Point3D> points = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(

            new Point3D(0, 90,0),
            new Point3D(0,150,0),

            new Point3D(40,150,0),
            new Point3D(40,90,0),

            new Point3D(30,90,0),
            new Point3D(30,0,0),

            new Point3D(10,0,0),
            new Point3D(10,90,0)
    )
            );
```

It is important that points are ordered forming a closed polygon.